# Taking Java Input Quickly

Tags: java, input

I am attempting to do a problem on Interview Street, my question is not related to the algorithm but to **Java**. For the challenge there is the need to take a somewhat large number of lines of input (several hundred thousand) from *System.in*. Each line has an expected pattern of two or three tokens so there is no need to do any validation or parsing (making *Scanner* ineffective). My own algorithm is correct and accounts for a very small portion of the overall run time (range of 5%-20% depending on the edge case).

Doing some research and testing I found that for this problem that the *BufferedReader* class is significantly faster than the *Scanner* class for getting the inputted data for this problem. However *BufferedReader* is still not quick enough for the purposes of the challenge. Could anyone point me to an article or API where I could research a better way of taking input?

If it important I am using *BufferedReader* by calling the readLine() method and *String* split() method to separate the tokens.

Comment: `String.split()` uses regular expressions, this may give some unnecessary overhead. Or may not. It is interesting, where is real bottleneck in your code. Did you try to increase size of buffer in `BufferedReader`? If so, did it influences on performance?

Comment: Are you using a BufferedInputStream? We need more info

Comment: For test purposes I am reading from a file using BufferedReader and FileReader, since I cannot enter data by hand quickly enough for BufferedReader and InputStreamReader. The bottleneck seems to be the input on the edge case of taking 500,000 inputs the program takes roughly an average of 130ms to finish. Commenting out everything but readLine() within the loop that runs 500,000 times reduces the run time to 110ms. Overhead wise though the tokens consist of 5 character string, an integer between 0 and 100,000, and maybe an integer value of 0 or 1. I don’t think split() should be that taxing.

Answer (score 1):

Without any useful information, the best I can do is provide a generalized answer: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/PerfTuning/

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few things (from the top of my head):

1. try to create your own reader, or even forget about converting to characters if it is not needed;
2. read in whole blocks, not just lines
3. try to optimize the buffer size;
4. walk through the chars or bytes yourself, trying to find the tokens
5. optimize the compiler output
6. pre-compile your classes for a fast startup
7. use a profiler to check for slow spots in your code

Use your brain and think out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

BufferedDataInputStream is supposed to be way faster than BufferedReader.
You can find the jar here: http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/apache/tika/tika-app/0.8/tika-app-0.8.jar!/nom/tam/util/BufferedDataInputStream.class?classDetails=ok.
The javadoc http://skyview.gsfc.nasa.gov/jar/javadocs/nom/tam/util/BufferedDataInputStream.html.
This is part of this project http://skyview.gsfc.nasa.gov/help/skyviewjava.html.

Note that I have never tested this...